# Kotlin build gradle ~ dependencies resolves as type DependencyHandlerScorpe instead of KotlinDependencyHandler

Tags: kotlin, gradle

I am currently observing the following very curious behavior in the `build.gradle.kts` files of one of my projects:

[image]

Basically, I have two modules, and the same import works in one, but not in the other. Upon close inspection, I have noted what I believe might be the root of the problem, though I have no idea why it happens or what to do against it.

The core of what I want to do is to get this import running:

```
kotlin {
    [...]
    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting
            dependencies {
                implementation(Dependencies.eventBus)
            }
        [...]
        }
    }
}
```

In the module on the left, that works just fine. However, in the module on the right, it doesn't. The differences that I can observe are that for some strange reason, the `getting` is syntax-highlighted in purple instead of yellow on the right, and `dependencies` is of the type `this: DependencyHandlerScope` instead of `this: KotlinDependencyHandler`.

And now the really strange thing: In the very next block below that (`commonTest`) it behaves "correctly" again (as in: like in the left module, where the import works).

What is going on here? Is this really the reason why my import fails to resolve? And if so, what can I do against it?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so after I spent a bit more time looking at it, I found the issue: I was missing a pair of curly braces around the `dependencies` block in that one case, so this is how it ought to look, which is visually very similar, yet syntactically apparently a big difference:

```
kotlin {
    [...]
    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(Dependencies.eventBus)
            }
        }
        [...]
    }
}
```